# View not refreshing using `this` context in Angular 1.6

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular and using 'this' instead of 'scope' as I checked for best practices. My initial value is reflected but change in value after function call is not getting reflected on view.

Here is my code:

**My HTML on the view**

```
    <div class="container" ng-controller="LoginCtrl as loginCtrl">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 title">Login</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12"><label>Email</label></div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" name="email" type="email" ng-model="loginCtrl.email"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12"><label>Password</label></div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="loginCtrl.password"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="loginCtrl.checkLogin()">Login</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <span>{!loginCtrl.message!}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <a href="{{$root}}/forgot-password">Forgot password</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**My main.js**

```
angular.module('app', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{!');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol('!}');
});
```

**My controller**

```
angular.module('app').controller('LoginCtrl', ['$window', 'LoginService', 'CSRF_TOKEN', function($window, LoginService, CSRF_TOKEN) {
this.message = 'Initial message';
this.email = '';
this.password = '';

this.checkLogin = function() {
    var data = {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password,
        _token: CSRF_TOKEN
    };

    LoginService.checkLogin(data)
        .then(function(result) {
            if (result.success)
                $window.location.replace('user-section');
            else
                this.message = result.message;
        });
}
}]);
```

Please assume that there are no errors on console and everything is fine.
**Initial message** is getting printed but `this.message = result.message` or `this.message = 'Some result';` is not getting reflected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with your `checkLogin` function.

In the function you set `this.message` to some string **inside another function**. This new function also creates a new scope. So whenever you use the keyword `this` inside the new function, it refers to the scope of the new function, not the scope of your controller.

To fix this you can add another variable `var self = this` outside the `checkLogin` function and use it as a reference for your controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('LoginCtrl', ['$window', 'LoginService', 'CSRF_TOKEN', function($window, LoginService, CSRF_TOKEN) {
this.message = 'Initial message';
this.email = '';
this.password = '';

var self = this;

this.checkLogin = function() {
    var data = {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password,
        _token: CSRF_TOKEN
    };

    LoginService.checkLogin(data)
        .then(function(result) {
            if (result.success)
                $window.location.replace('user-section');
            else
                self.message = result.message;
        });
}
}]);
```

Inside of the new function you can now call `self.message`, because `self` still refers to your controller, so this will update the message in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `LoginService` is using a native promise instead of `$q` so angular is not aware of your async changes. You need to run a digest cycle when your data is fetched. Try this:

```
LoginService.checkLogin(data)
    .then((result) => {
        if (result.success)
            $window.location.replace('user-section');
        else
            $scope.apply(function () {
                this.message = result.message;
            });
       });
```

> Notice the arrow function so you don't lose the reference to your scope.